# Error with build in Visual Studio (C++) (files/directories are missing?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

after installing the community version of Visual Studio 2019 I was able to open projects and to write code but if I want to start the program following error appears: "Error while creating, do you want to continue and open the last build?"...if I select yes:
"The program"C:\Users\user\source\repos\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe" can not be started. The system couldnt find the file".
I tried to reintall Viusal Studio multiple times but the error still occurs.
This also shows up if I try to run the "HelloWorld" program from Visual Studio so I assume the code isnt responible for the error.

Following appears too:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "crtdbg.h": No such file or directory

All together there are 412 files missing ore undefined.

Comment: Probably this indicates that you need to download the `Windows 10 SDK` Use the Visual Studio Installer do download this component.

Comment: I have `crtdbg.h` located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\crtdbg.h`, so john is correct, you have to install Windows SDK, also it might be probably called Windows Kit. It is a part of MSVC installer under Individual Components tab.

Comment: I already installed Windows 10 SDK multiple times with the Visual Studio installer but I cant find files in the location you mentioned.

Comment: @Robert I expect that you used official MSVC installer, right? From [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/). Then under Individual Components you installed `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)`, right? After that your header files should appear either under path from my previous comment, or it could be that it is under same path but inside `C:\Program Files\...` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`. If not there, then try searching for file `crtdbg.h` on your whole disk (all drives). It should be somewhere definitely. MSVC may have installed in another dir.

Comment: Thank you... and yeah I downloaded the intaller from there and activated Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0) as an individual component. Unfortunatley I couldnt find the file  despite searching on all drives :/

Comment: I just installed the 10.0.19041.0 version and it works! Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it :)